# Outlook VBA troubleshooting

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010, type-mismatch

I have the following block of VBA code, which should create a popup box with the first name for each contact in my default folder.

```
Sub DeleteaContact()
   Dim myOutlook As Outlook.Application
   Dim myInformation As NameSpace
   Dim myContacts As Items
   Dim myItems As ContactItem

   Set myOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set myInformation = myOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   Set myContacts = myInformation.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items

    For Each myItems In myContacts
      MsgBox (myItems.FirstName)
    Next

End Sub
```

For some reason I am getting a sporadic type mismatch error at the end of the loop.

Can anyone shed some light on this subject as to why?

Answer (score 1):

Folders can store more than just the data type you'd expect.  Change myItems to

```
Dim myItems As Object
```

and change the message box to

```
Debug.Print TypeName(myItems)
```

Then check the Immediate Window (Ctl+G) to see if any of the items are not ContactItem.  If you determine you have something in there that's not a contact, you simply need to test for it.  Keep myItems as Object, but use code like

```
If TypeName(myItems) = "ContactItem" Then
    MsgBox myItems.FirstName
End If
```

Generally, I leave my variables typed as the specific item (e.g. ContactItem) while I'm writing the code and then convert them all to Object when I'm done.  That way you get the benefit of Intellisense while you're coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

`MsgBox (myItems.FirstName)`

to:

`MsgBox myItems.FirstName`

as VBA doesn't like unnecessary parentheses